# How do I show only particular data from a PouchDB?

Tags: pouchdb

Right now, my output looks like this when using a PouchDB database:

```
{"occupation":"kitten","cuteness":6,"_id":"abby","_rev":"1-3659256a0c4ef8bea1a3b3ef776569fa"}
[etc]...
```

However, I want it to output like this:

```
kitten | 6 | abby
[etc]...
```

How do I do that? I'm using db.bulkDocs code.

```
        ... ]).then(function() {
            return db.allDocs({
                include_docs: true
            });
        }).then(function(result) {
            var out = '';
            var i = 0;
            result.rows.forEach(function() {
                while (i < 5) {
                    out = JSON.stringify(result.rows[i].doc) + '<br>';
                    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += out;
                    i++;
                }
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I need to use the following syntax if I want to retrieve just one document:

```
    db.get("1", function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Failed to get document");
        } else {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += doc.occupation + ', ' + doc.cuteness + ', ' + doc._id + '<br>';
        }
    });
```